# Ratpack handlers -how to add more than one prefixes

Tags: ratpack

I am trying to add  kind of hello/name (for health check) for my app but I do not want to do that part of my chainAction.

```
.handlers(chain -> chain
                .prefix("api", TaskChainAction.class))
        );
```

What it takes to add second hello greeting without using  "api" prefix?

I tried

```
.handlers(chain-> chain
                    .get("/:name", ctx -> ctx.render("Hello"+ctx.getPathTokens().get("name"))))
                .handlers(chain -> chain
                    .prefix("task", TaskChainAction.class))
            );
```

and

```
.handlers(chain-> chain
                    .get("/:name", ctx -> ctx.render("Hello"+ctx.getPathTokens().get("name"))))
                .handlers(chain -> chain
                .prefix("task", TaskChainAction.class))
```

No luck..

I am okay with adding second prefix e.g /greetings/hello. Adding second prefix is not working either.

I am using 1.4.6 version of ratpack. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order is super important in the handler chain. The request flows from the top to the bottom, so your least-specific bindings should be at the bottom.

For what you're trying to do, you can do something like:

```
RatpackServer.start(spec -> spec
  .handlers(chain -> chain
    .prefix("api", ApiTaskChain.class)
    .path(":name", ctx -> 
      ctx.render("Hello World")
    )
  )
);
```

Also, you should not add `/`'s explicitly to your path bindings. A binding's position in its current chain dictates the preceding path, so `/` is unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you Dan. I think I had "/" in front of the name.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I use in my ratpack.groovy file for the handler chain with multiple paths:

```
handlers{
  path("path_here"){
    byMethod{
      get{
        //you can pass the context to a handler like so:
        context.insert(context.get(you_get_handler)}
      post{
        //or you can handle inline
       }
    }
 }
 path("another_path_here") {
        byMethod {
            get {}
            put {}
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thank John. I chose the Dan's answer coz i wanted the prefix solution